# There are too many writes to properties at this time. Please wait up to 12 hours for the changes to be processed

Tags: google-sheets, add-on

I am getting "There are too many writes to properties at this time. Please wait up to 12 hours for the changes to be processed." when try to read or write properties using PropertiesService class. 
Originally I thought the script hit daily quotes and I stopped the script for 24 hours, but after 24 hours I got the same error, however there were no any account activity for 24 hours. 
Is it still the issue with quotes ? Is it quote issues or something else ?
Thanks,
Andrey.